# Not able to start Jupyter Notebook on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Anaconda Jupyter notebook is not starting through command prompt when I provide the command `jupyter notebook`. I'm getting this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to activate anaconda `conda activate` then `jupyter notebook`